# Do I have to learn node.js in order to use npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to use a package on npm, so I'm trying to learn how to use npm. The tutorials are fine, but I feel like they're assuming I know node.js, which I don't, and I'm having a hard time finding a tutorial for npm that doesn't also assume I know node.js. Do I need to learn node.js to use npm?

Comment: Since also client side libraries can be downloaded using npm and if that is what you want to use npm for then no you don't need to learn node.js

Comment: @Kyll It is my understanding that while npm was originally "just a package manager for Node", it has grown to be much more than that and is a package manager for JavaScript in general. And you're equating Node with JavaScript, which I don't think is accurate either. I'm obviously new to this, can you please explain?

Comment: Do _you_ feel like you need to learn Node.js to be able to do what you want with `npm`? That's literally the only question that needs to be answered, considering this is so broad and depends entirely on the person and their situation.

Comment: I don't see this question as opinion based. It seems like a simple yes or no question: is node.js required to use npm?

Comment: @John It's an opinion based question because some people would say Yes, some would say No, and some would say Maybe. I'm in the maybe camp because, again, it depends _entirely_ on what you are trying to use `npm` for. It can be used to distribute command-line tools, create back-end and front-end modules, full-stack applications, etc. If you're doing back-end, yes, you need to learn Node.js. If you're doing front-end, you'll need to learn a middleware loader. At the very least you'll need to understand CommonJS module formats. It's _just_ a package manager for JS - how you use it is up to you.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation, that helps. I've been doing JS for FED for three years and this is all new to me. So if I want to use an npm module for a website (front-end), I need to learn a middleware loader as you suggested, right? /overwhelmed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you don't need to know anything about node to use npm, its just a package manager.  [Install npm](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/85484771375/how-to-install-npm) and then `npm install` all the packages you want.  You will need to learn the npm [toolchain](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm), however, and it also helps to know which options are available for the various commands.

At the very least you should know the difference between [installing a package globally and installing a package locally](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), i.e `npm install -g` vs. `npm install` respectively.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I've never used a package manager before, so this is all new to me. I've looked over the tutorials on the npm site and they explain the toolchain that you've detailed above. I believe I installed the modules that I need locally, but the next step eludes me. I know this is totally a newb question, but how do I use this on my website? I'm used to calling jQuery using the src attribute of a script tag, but I get the sense that using a module on npm is not done the same way.

Comment: If your going to be using npm packages on the front end, take a look at  browserify: http://browserify.org/