# Do i need to learn Nodejs to understand and work with NPM?

Tags: node.js, npm, packaging

Today most of developers use NPM to manage their things. I know what NPM and NodeJS are but i'm a bit confused about how NPM works! should i have to learn NodeJS to understand NPM?

Comment: You will no doubt need to learn what NPM is if you want to do a lot of node programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this guy asks a question similar to yours:

[do-i-have-to-learn-node-js-in-order-to-use-npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876022/do-i-have-to-learn-node-js-in-order-to-use-npm)

but i think you mean something else and your question about understanding what NPM really is!
if you simply google to what npm is you will find:

> npm, short for Node Package Manager, is two things: first and foremost, it is an online repository for the publishing of open-source Node.js projects; second, it is a command-line utility for interacting with said repository that aids in package installation, version management, and dependency management

by Mr. Nico Reed. source: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/npm/what-is-npm/

Nodejs has some tools like npm and nvm. Npm(node package manager) is a package manager. It let's you install software (libraries, plugins, frameworks and applications). Typically this software is installed to build Node applications.